# Can the Glassfish Admin Console have multiple users with certain privileges?

Tags: glassfish-3, user-permissions

I am new to Glassfish (3.1.2.2) and was wondering if I could log into the Admin Console with a user that has only privileges to modify JNDI properties. I could not find anywhere saying that you can or cannot have multiple users for the Admin console with different privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple users for the Admin Console but there is no possibility to modify the access rights via the Admin Console. 
It looks like it is possible to create a user with read-only access. It is described [here](http://logicoy.com/logicoyblog/?p=109). Maybe this method can be extended to fit your use-case.

Comment: I found this a few days ago but it did not work and did not fit my use-case. :(
Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. :)